# Django query created object in tests not working

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I have this code in a django test:

```
stockitem_retailer = StockItem.objects.filter(retailer=test_retailer).first()
test_subcategory = SubCategory.objects.create(category=test_category, name="outdoors")
stockitem_retailer.product.subcategory = test_subcategory
stockitem_retailer.save()
pdb.set_trace()

self.assertTrue(StockItem.objects.filter(product__subcategory=test_subcategory, retailer=test_retailer).exists())
```

The code above gets a `StockItem` object with `retailer=test_retailer`, then id adds a created subcategory "outdoors" to the `stockitem.product.subcategory` relation. Why then the test does not pass?

This is what I get from `pdb`:

```
(Pdb) test_subcategory
<SubCategory: outdoors>
(Pdb) test_retailer
<Retailer: mi-super>
(Pdb) stockitem_retailer.product.subcategory
<SubCategory: outdoors>
(Pdb) stockitem_retailer.retailer
<Retailer: mi-super>
(Pdb) self.assertTrue(StockItem.objects.filter(product__subcategory=test_subcategory, retailer=test_retailer).exists())
*** AssertionError: False is not true
```

I've being looking at this code for hours now, I can't se the bug. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You set `test_subcategory` on `stockitem_retailer.product`, but you never save `stockitem_retailer.product`, you only save `stockitem_retailer`.

Simply add `stockitem_retailer.product.save()` to save the product.